# Creating an arrow with :before

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm kind of stuck on this. I tried creating an arrow that will appear with the "Active" slide, and used :before however, the arrow is stuck in the box, and I can't move it outside the box and position in on the border so it's seamless. What am I doing wrong? I tried in a jsfiddle, and it seems to work fine, so  my guess is there is an issue with the other elements on the slider.

```
.evoslider.default .controlNav li.rotator.active:before
{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid #225985;
content: " ";
left: 0px;
top: 35px;
z-index: 100000;
position: absolute;
}
```

[Not working example](http://bestinslot.org),
[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/k6c9qam4/)

Comment: does your li, rotator or active styles set the 'position' attribute?

Comment: .evoslider .control_wrapper {
position: relative;
}

Comment: evoslider .controlNav li.rotator {
position: relative; 
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
overflow: hidden;

Comment: However, I'm not sure changing is an option without breaking the slider.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your website and the arrow isn't appearing because of the `overflow: hidden` property assigned to a few of its parent containers. Please add the following CSS to the bottom of your stylesheet and that would solve the problem:

```
li.rotator.active:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #225985;
    content: " ";
    left: -11px;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: 100000;
    position: absolute;
}

.evoslider.default .controlNav li.rotator {
     overflow: visible !important;
}

.evoslider.default .control_wrapper {
     overflow: visible !important;
}

.evoslider .outer_control {
     overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I've tested it using the developer tools and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I also checked your website and have verified that `overflow: hidden` is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your box has `position: relative` on it, you can set `left: -10px` on the `:before` style

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k6c9qam4/3/**